# how do I scrape hoverable drop-down menus with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to scrape a web page that contains hoverable menus but they don't appear in resulting html.

I want the resulting page to look the same as the original page but can't scrape the hoverable elements. I'm doing something wrong for sure. thanks for help

```
url = 'https://www.classcentral.com'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv: geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion')
options.add_argument('referer = https://www.classcentral.com/')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
step = driver.get_window_size()['height'] // 2
achains = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//*[contains(text(), 'Courses')]|//*[@value=Courses])")))
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-name='LARGE_UP_MAIN_NAV_TRIGGER']")
achains.move_to_element(button).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//nav[@class='main-nav-dropdown js-main-nav-dropdown is-open']")))
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//nav[@class='main-nav-dropdown js-main-nav-dropdown is-open']")
achains.move_to_element(button).perform()
time.sleep(1)
achains.move_by_offset(0, 100)
time.sleep(1)

for line in range(0, scroll_height, step):
    driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo({line}, {line + step})')
driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo({scroll_height}, 0)')

dirname = 'classcentral'
!mkdir 'classcentral'
if url ==  'https://www.classcentral.com':
    pagetitle = 'index'
else:
    pagetitle = driver.title
with open('/'.join((dirname, f'{pagetitle}.html')), 'w') as ouf:
    ouf.write(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If so, at which line of code is the error raised?